# elasticbundle search an index

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

Good Morning,

I would like some help for FOSElastcaBundle. I have a installed elasticsearch with kibana and logstash. I have an index named openvpn and there is the _type rsyslog-openvpn. I would like to get some entry, for the element where the fiels common_name is equal to PLPM0046.

I installed FOSElasticaBundle but I cannot seems to make it work.

Here is my configuration so far:
config.yml

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: ip.to.server.elastic, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        openvpn:
            client: default
            types:
                rsyslog-openvpn:
                    mappings:
                        common_name: ~
                        logsource: ~
```

action

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.index.openvpn.rsyslog-openvpn');
$results = $finder->find('PLPM0046');
```

I did as it is presented in the documentation, but I get this errors:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "fos_elastica.index.openvpn.rsyslog-openvpn".
```

I anyone knosw how this bundle work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i can read my working code, you can get the finder like:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.openvpn.rsyslog-openvpn');
```

additionally add `finder: ~`  to your index

```
    indexes:
        openvpn:
            client: default
            finder: ~
            types:
                rsyslog-openvpn:
                    mappings:
                        ...
                    persistence:
                        finder: ~
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, unfortunately I does not work, I get the same error, expect that now it i srelated to  fos_elastic.finder.openvpn.rsyslog-openvpn. I can get teh finder for  fos_elastic.finder.openvpn but not for rsyslog-openvpn

Comment: check my update, you need to add `finder: ~ ` also to your rsyslog-openvpn   type persistence entry, to be able to retrieve the specific "type-finder"

Comment: Ok, do I also need to set the driver and an entity corresponding to my mapping ?

Comment: I managed to do it, not by using finder, but index, thanks to your help I managed to find the problem ^^